# Overridden by second object insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am  just wondering why my second insertion will overwrite my first object values.

```js
const customer = {
    name: '',
    totalCups: 0
}

$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
  debugger

  var itemName = $('#customerName');
  var itemTotalCups = $('#customerTotalCups');

  // Basic Validation
  if (itemName.val().trim() === "") {
    return;
  }

  if (parseInt(itemTotalCups.val()) === 0) {
    return;
  }

  customer.name = itemName.val();
  customer.totalCups = itemTotalCups.val();

  // Data structure Queue
  order.unshift(customer);
  console.log(order);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="customerName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter customer's name" />
  <input id="customerTotalCups" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter number of cups" min="1" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
</div>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>

<div id="CurentOrder"></div>
```

The first insertion for example I get,

```
0: {name: "Alan", totalCups: "1"}
```

and when I execute .unshift for the second insertion with another data, it becomes below:

```
0: {name: "Alan", totalCups: "1"}
1: {name: "Alan", totalCups: "1"}
```

Comment: For a start you haven't defined `customer`.

Comment: sorry. miss out

Comment: Maybe it's the same reference and you just keep adding the same object

Comment: Nope @MoritzRoessler - shouldn't happen because he's changing the values each time.

Comment: @JackBashford but he's not creating a new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a func, every time it changes "global" object `customer`, then you try to put customer's copy to `order` array. Hence after customer properties change, all its copies are changed as well. To avoid such behavior you need to use `Object.assign()` method to populate `order`:

```
order.unshift(Object.assign({}, customer));
```

```js
const customer = {
    name: '',
    totalCups: 0
}

$('#btnAdd').on('click', function() {
  var itemName = $('#customerName').val().trim();
  var itemTotalCups = $('#customerTotalCups').val();

  // Basic Validation
  if ( (itemName === "") || (parseInt(itemTotalCups) === 0) ) return;

  customer.name = itemName;
  customer.totalCups = itemTotalCups;

  // Data structure Queue
  order.unshift(Object.assign({}, customer));
  console.log(order);
})

var order = [];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="customerName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter customer's name" />
  <input id="customerTotalCups" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter number of cups" min="1" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
</div>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>

<div id="CurentOrder"></div>
```

One more note - you created two html elements with the same `id="btnAdd"`, but `id` should be unique identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Try and run the following code to see what happens to the customer object and the order array, specifically on the second call. It should become clear what the problem is :)

```js
const customer = {
    name: '',
    totalCups: 0
}
let i = 0;
let order = [];

function add () {
  customer.name = i++
  customer.totalCups = Math.random ()

  // Data structure Queue
  order.unshift(customer);
  console.log(order);
}

add ();
add ();

console.log (order)
console.log (order [0] === order [1])
```

Comment: Hint: create the customer object in the add function to create a new instnance everytime - or even better, write a function that does it.